# Помощь с Func для Dictionary

Tags: c#, делегаты

Подскажите как должен выглядеть предикат, чтобы его можно было закинуть в OrderBy.

Словарь имеет вид `Dictionary<string, List<Person>> data`.

Мне нужно отсортировать `List<Person>` следующим образом: есть какой-то `Func<Person, object> predicate`, который я должен использовать здесь - `data.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value.OrderBy(predicate))`. Но он ругается, т.е. предикат не правильный, подскажите как он должен выглядеть.

P.s. пробовал такой: `Func<KeyValuePair<string, List<Person>>, Person, object> predicate`, используя его так: `data.OrderBy(predicate)`, но это тоже не то.

Comment: `... он ругается, ... это тоже не то.` Это же не первый Ваш вопрос здесь. Пора бы уже запомнить что когда возникают ошибки нужно выкладывать полное и 
 точное сообщение об ошибке. Еще нужно научиться составлять пример кода для демонстрации ошибки.

Comment: Почитайте на английском SO этот вопрос и ответы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403615/predicates-and-orderby-func

Comment: Начните с того, что надо понять, что такое предикат, и что он должен возвращать. Есть даже класс такой [`Predicate<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8). А у вас функция возвращает `object`. Почему `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OrderBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) принимает функцию, в которой тип первого параметра совпадает с типом элемента коллекции, а возвращаемое значение - это значение которое будет сравниваться при сортировке.

---

Если у тебя есть словарь `Dictionary<string, List<Person>> data` а отсортировать нужно `List<Person>`, то `OrderBy` нужно вызывать не у `data`, а у конкретного элемента словаря.

В этом случае функция должна принимать `Person` и возвращать какое-то значение, которое можно использовать для сравнения, например `Func<Person, int>` → `person => person.Age`

И вызывать для конкретного элемента: `data[key].OrderBy(person => person.Age)`